# C# Yield return list, not single object

Tags: c#, yield-return

I need batch wise sublist to process objects in batch. Parallel.ForEach is not feasible as the batch is posted to the HTTP request.

```
public IEnumerable<T> BatchProcess<T>(IEnumerable<T> list, int batchSize)
    {
        int page = 0;
        IEnumerable<T> batch;
        while ((batch = list.Skip(page).Take(batchSize)).Count() != 0)
        {
            page++;
            yield return batch; //Error CS0029  Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<T>' to 'T'
        }

    }
```

Error   CS0029  Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List' to 'T'.

Expecting "yeild return" to return a list of objects instead of returning a single object.

Comment: See "InBatches" from my personal extensions library (feel free to loot it).  https://github.com/thesoftwarejedi/Torian.Common/blob/master/Source/Extensions/Enumerables.cs

Comment: Yup, it's duplicate.

Comment: Yup, just offering a prewritten library to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your method signature should be

```
public IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> BatchProcess<T>(IEnumerable<T> list, int batchSize)
```

Comment: There should also be an incremental operation on page